# APK Expansion Files is saved to shared storage. How to keep privacy?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have designed an app which contains various mp4 clips, and the apk is larger than 100mb. So after reading what to do, I realised to use APK Expansion Files.

However I read the following on the Android developers information:

Note: Unlike APK files, any files saved on the shared storage can be read by the user and other applications.

Now, these videos I have worked on designing etc, and I don't want them to be available to the user in the shared storage.

What can I do in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Host them on a server. Download them from the server to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) using an HTTP client API (e.g., `HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp).

Comment: This "internal storage" is also available to read by the user?

Comment: No, except on rooted devices.